# How do websockets work in detail?

Tags: websocket, socket.io, spring-websocket, java-websocket, libwebsockets

There's a [fantastic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671118/what-exactly-is-restful-programming/671132#671132) which goes into detail as to how REST apis work.

How do websockets work in the similar detail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Websockets create and represent a standard for bi-directional communication between a server and client.  This communication channel creates a TCP connection which is outside of HTTP and is run on a seperate server.
To start this process a handshake is performed between the server and client.

Here is the work flow

1) The user makes an HTTP request to the server with an upgrade header, indicating that the client wishes to establish a WebSocket connection.

2) If the server uses the WebSocket protocol, then it will accept the upgrade and send a response back.

3) With the handshake finished, the WebSocket protocol is used from now on.  All communications will use the same underlying TCP port. The new returning status code, 101, signifies Switching Protocols.

As part of HTML5 it should work with most modern browsers.